# PHP, how to access value in associative array when key is an int

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an array like this:

```
$sizing = array(
    "4" => "US 4 - EU XXS",
    "5" => "US 5 - EU XS",
    "6" => "US 6 - EU S",
    "7" => "US 7 - EU M",
    "8" => "US 8 - EU L",   
    );
```

Later in the code I need to find out the value from this array where the number is stored in `$size`

I'm trying

```
$new_size = $sizing["$size"];
```

but receive an error that

`Notice: Undefined index: 4`

I'm assuming this is because I'm using a number as the key and PHP thinks its referring to an index rather than a named key.

How can I do this better? Thank you.

Comment: Y cant u try $sizing[(string)$size];

Comment: Nothing wrong with that syntax, something else is going wrong.  `$sizing["4"]` is definitely valid.

Comment: `$size=4;echo $new_size = $sizing["$size"];`

Comment: @Madbreaks You are correct. There was an errant space in `$size` Adding `trim()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $sizing = array(
    4 => "US 4 - EU XXS",
    "US 5 - EU XS",
    "US 6 - EU S",
    "US 7 - EU M",
    "US 8 - EU L"   
    );
    $size = 4;    
    echo $sizing[$size]; //US 4 - EU XXS
```